# Android Project build target greater than what it is meant to work for

Tags: android, admob

In my android app I'm using admob and I was just about to integrate the last admob sdk (GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.3.1). After adding it to my project I had some runtime errors:

```
11-20 14:24:10.234: E/Ads(14268): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include keyboard.
11-20 14:24:10.234: E/Ads(14268): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include screenLayout.
11-20 14:24:10.234: E/Ads(14268): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include uiMode.
11-20 14:24:10.234: E/Ads(14268): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include screenSize.
11-20 14:24:10.234: E/Ads(14268): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include smallestScreenSize.
11-20 14:24:10.234: E/Ads(14268): You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges.
```

And in the ad banner: "You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges."
After searching the stackoverflow I've added all the configChanges above:

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

But now I have the error below:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').    AndroidManifest.xml line 22 Android AAPT Problem
```

Now to fix this I have to set the Project build target Android 3.2 (API Level 13) or above.

Can anyone tell me what does this imply? Will the app work well on all Android 2.1+ ?

Please note that before this, my project build target was Android 2.1, and my test device is Nexus S (2.3.6) on which the app is working well even after setting the build target to 3.2+.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything will work fine even if you build against 3.2

What I do is leave it all on 3.2, then when I'm done coding it and ready to test, I switch it back down the minimum level that my app should support, I check for any errors that come up. (the one in the manifest will not matter). I do this because it's easy to miss accidentally adding 2.3 code when you want it to work on 2.1

Answer (score 2):

Just remove everything after orientation, problem solved

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: Not really, if you use the last admob sdk is not working... anyway.

Comment: This set of configChanges is only valid for AdMob SDKs version 4.1.1 and lower.

Answer (score 0):

Google AdMob Ads SDK 4.3.1 requires you to compile against Android 3.2 or above (This means in your `project.properties` file you need to specify `android-13` or higher).  Your app will still run fine on 2.1+ devices; you just have to specify you support 2.1 in your manifest.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  I've clarified what "compile against" means in my answer.  You'll need to set `android-13` in your `project.properties` file because some of the configChanges weren't introduced until API level 13.  but the `minSdkVersion="7"` attribute will tell Android to allow phones with Android 2.1 to download your app - you'll just have to test to make sure that your app does still in fact work on Android 2.1.

Comment: oups, the reply was for another answer, sorry.

Comment: Where do we find this project.properties file ??

Comment: It should be in the top level directory of your Android project.  It used to be called `default.properties` a long time ago.  The value of the target in `project.properties` tells Android what version to compile against.